# Python3 List: How do I remove el in list_a if el[0] is not in list_b?

Tags: list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Let's say 
a = [(1, 'CA'), (2, 'NY)]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]

How do I remove el in a if el[0] is not in b? In this case, I want to remove (1, 'CA') since 1 is not on b. I tried to use for el in list_a but it didn't work since the list kept changing.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you'll be repeatedly checking if elements are in `b`, [convert `b` to a set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) first, so each check is `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`. Then you can use the [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[el for el in a if el[0] in bset]
```

---

```
a = [(1, 'CA'), (2, 'NY')]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]
bset = set(b)

a = [el for el in a if el[0] in bset]
print(a)
```

yields

```
[(2, 'NY')]
```

---

Note: if `a` is really short, *not* converting to a set is actually faster:

```
In [4]: %timeit bset = set(b); [el for el in a if el[0] in bset]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 580 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit [el for el in a if el[0] in b]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 335 ns per loop
```

However, if `a` is long, then converting `b` to a set really pays off:

```
In [47]: a = a*1000

In [48]: %timeit bset = set(b); [el for el in a if el[0] in bset]
10000 loops, best of 3: 157 us per loop

In [49]: %timeit [el for el in a if el[0] in b]
10 loops, best of 3: 37.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: thanks! btw what are this kind of operations called? i would want to look up more info about it. thanks!

Comment: The two main ideas are [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner. The `bset=set(b)` is only executed once

```
>>> a = [(1, 'CA'), (2, 'NY')]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a[:] = filter(lambda x, bset=set(b): x[0] in bset, a)
>>> a
[(2, 'NY')]
```